# Jquery UI datepicker cut off a day from the date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am showing different required dates in a form and I am facing a weird issue on server but not on my localhost. For clarifying I have made a screenshot showing the problem.

Please relate the following points with the image with help of the text in brackets at the end of the point.

- Initially we set the date in the input type text element and converts it to the datepicker. Now user can select new dates with help of datepciker or just save the predefined date. (Entered into Form)
- Dates are displayed in a simple HTML page for user after form is submitted. At this point we can see dates entered and date displayed are same. (Post Submit - Display on Page 2)
- Now when user again visit the edit form, all of the dates are cut off by one day. (subtracting one day)

For your information I have test it with different techniques,

- Creating Javascript Date object with hours and minutes.

  $('#datepicker_input').datepicker().datepicker({'setDate', new Date('2015-02-02T00:00:00'})).datepicker('update');
- Forcefully setting date as UTC

  $('#datepicker_input').datepicker('useLocalTimezone': false).datepicker({'setDate', new Date(new Date('2015-02-02T00:00:00'})).toGMTString())).datepicker('update');

Thanks in advance

[image]

**HTML input value is correct but datepicker calendar subtracting a day**

[image]

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle

Comment: I am afraid I cannot its only happening on my server and not my localhost. It seems to have some timezone issue. It may work perfectly on the jsfiddle and that is why I create the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be some kind of time-zone issue, but probably not directly with the JQuery. What language(s) are you using to store the dates / create the JQuery / write the test lines you've included? Try looking closer at the storage/retrieval rather than the JQuery.

Comment: I am using python to retrieve the data from MySQL database and then I set value of the input type text with the date. For HTML template I am using jinja2. Date value seems perfect in the HTML console if I inspect element but it just not appeared correctly in the datepicker calendar, it just cut offs a day as I showed in the screenshot.

Comment: Have you checked that the data stored the MySQL database is actually correct, and is still what you expect when you retrieve it?

Comment: Data stored accurately in the database, Data retrieved perfectly from the database and it even shows perfectly in the HTML Console of browser but datepicker calendar subtract a day from the actual date.

Comment: I have just added another screenshot in the question description, you can see in the console the value of the input element is showing correct (which is what I saved) but the calendar of the datepicker is just subtracting one day.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it's a problem with calling of the JQuery setDate(), then. Instead of using a Date object, try simply using a string: $("#datepicker_input").datepicker('setDate', '01/15/2015');
(Remember to use the correct formatting for the date string, though: you may have to format it on output from MySQL or Python.)

Comment: Please, show the HTML for the four input. I want to see the id and classes of each of them. Looks like all the four input have the same id.